# Script not running first time in console, does afterwards

Tags: powershell

Hoping you can help as I have run out of ideas and at this point I think it is because I don't understand PowerShell properly.

I read this series; https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/ and tried to do the same thing, then I discovered that I could not call my script by opening a normal PowerShell console (Not ISE) and doing .\script.ps1

I also noticed that I could not do the same with the example script located here;

https://github.com/1RedOne/BlogPosts/blob/master/GUI%20Part%20V/PowerShell_GUI_Template.ps1

It does run the SECOND time however and every time after that? For example if you do

```
.\script.ps1 (doesn't work)
.\script.ps1 (works)
.\script.ps1 (works)
etc...
```

But if you do

```
powershell .\script.ps1 (doesn't work)
powershell .\script.ps1 (doesn't work)
```

However if you close ISE, open it again and run script it works first time?

I don't really know what is causing this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

If you would like to see this just copy from github link as that one has same problem as mine.

Comment: Thanks man, you found an error in my code!  Mathias sent a pull request to me and I've fixed the code on my site and in my repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to line 39-41 in the script on GitHub:

```
$syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
```

As you can see, `presentationframework.dll` is not being loaded into the appdomain until *after* [`XamlReader.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190359(v=vs.95).aspx) is being called.

The entire rest of the script is dependant on the output from this call, so the entire thing fails.

Second time around, the `presentationframework` assembly has already been loaded, so the call succeeds and the Window is created correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wouldn't have worked that out myself, that has resolved it, works first time now :)